# Windows Driver, creating/mounting a disk device from kernel

Tags: c, windows, kernel, driver, wdk

I have been stuck with a problem for 3 weeks now, and would really like to
move on to the "real porting" work of filling in the filesystem code. I am
trying to simulate a dynamic mount request, issued from userland to the
kernel driver. So it is about the kernel side code.

I have been reading the sources to Dokan, and win-btrfs
and a bunch of others, which does similar things. Ie, create a new fake
disk device, and somehow get it to have a "Volume" which gets assigned
a drive letter, and filesystem requests come pouring in...

I would like to believe (hah) that I am close...  I have simplified the
sources as much as possible, to assist with reading, and similarly
cleaned up the log, replacing hex addresses with variable names.

I generate the uuid based on the name, and I put the name used in
comment before the call.

```
handle_mount_request_and_create_volume()
{
deviceCharacteristics = FILE_DEVICE_IS_MOUNTED;
deviceCharacteristics |= FILE_REMOVABLE_MEDIA;

// First create the disk device object,
// WIN_DriverObject is the DriverEntry object
status = IoCreateDeviceSecure(WIN_DriverObject,
    sizeof(myfs_mount_object_t),
    // '\Device\Volume{0b1bb601-af0b-32e8-a1d2-54c167af6277}'
    &diskDeviceName,
    FILE_DEVICE_DISK,
    deviceCharacteristics,
    FALSE,
    &SDDL_DEVOBJ_SYS_ALL_ADM_RWX_WORLD_RW_RES_R,
    NULL,
    &diskDeviceObject);

myfs_mount_object_t *zmo_dcb = diskDeviceObject->DeviceExtension;
// '\Device\Volume{0b1bb601-af0b-32e8-a1d2-54c167af6277}'
AsciiStringToUnicodeString(buf, &zmo_dcb->device_name);

// '\DosDevices\Global\Volume{0b1bb601-af0b-32e8-a1d2-54c167af6277}'
AsciiStringToUnicodeString(buf, &zmo_dcb->symlink_name);

// '\Device\Myfs{0b1bb601-af0b-32e8-a1d2-54c167af6277}'
AsciiStringToUnicodeString(buf, &zmo_dcb->fs_name);

diskDeviceObject->Flags |= DO_DIRECT_IO;

// Now create the filesystem device object
status = IoCreateDeviceSecure(
    WIN_DriverObject,
    sizeof(myfs_mount_object_t),
    // '\Device\Myfs{0b1bb601-af0b-32e8-a1d2-54c167af6277}'
    &fsDeviceName,
    FILE_DEVICE_DISK_FILE_SYSTEM,
    deviceCharacteristics,
    FALSE,
    &SDDL_DEVOBJ_SYS_ALL_ADM_RWX_WORLD_RW_RES_R,
    NULL,
    &fsDeviceObject);

myfs_mount_object_t *zmo_vcb = fsDeviceObject->DeviceExtension;

dprintf("WinDeviceObject : %p\n", WIN_DriverObject);
dprintf("diskDeviceObject: %p\n", diskDeviceObject);
dprintf("fsDeviceObject  : %p\n", fsDeviceObject);

// '\Device\Myfs{0b1bb601-af0b-32e8-a1d2-54c167af6277}'
AsciiStringToUnicodeString(buf, &zmo_vcb->device_name);

// '\DosDevices\Global\Volume{0b1bb601-af0b-32e8-a1d2-54c167af6277}'
AsciiStringToUnicodeString(buf, &zmo_vcb->symlink_name);

fsDeviceObject->Flags |= DO_DIRECT_IO;

diskDeviceObject->Vpb->DeviceObject = fsDeviceObject;
diskDeviceObject->Vpb->RealDevice = fsDeviceObject;
diskDeviceObject->Vpb->Flags |= VPB_MOUNTED;
diskDeviceObject->Vpb->VolumeLabelLength = wcslen(VOLUME_LABEL) * sizeof(WCHAR);
RtlStringCchCopyW(diskDeviceObject->Vpb->VolumeLabel,
    sizeof(diskDeviceObject->Vpb->VolumeLabel) / sizeof(WCHAR),
    VOLUME_LABEL);
diskDeviceObject->Vpb->SerialNumber = 0x19831116;

ObReferenceObject(fsDeviceObject);
ObReferenceObject(diskDeviceObject);

// Create symlink for userland
// '\DosDevices\Global\Volume{0b1bb601-af0b-32e8-a1d2-54c167af6277}'
// '\Device\Volume{0b1bb601-af0b-32e8-a1d2-54c167af6277}'
status = IoCreateSymbolicLink(&symbolicLinkTarget, &diskDeviceName);

// Mark devices as initialized
diskDeviceObject->Flags &= ~DO_DEVICE_INITIALIZING;
fsDeviceObject->Flags &= ~DO_DEVICE_INITIALIZING;

// Send IOCTL_MOUNTMGR_VOLUME_ARRIVAL_NOTIFICATION on the
// diskDeviceObject to MountMgr
// '\Device\Volume{0b1bb601-af0b-32e8-a1d2-54c167af6277}'
SendVolumeArrivalNotification(&diskDeviceName);

// register objects
status = IoReportDetectedDevice(
    WIN_DriverObject,
    InterfaceTypeUndefined,
    0, 0, NULL, NULL, FALSE,
    &pnpDeviceObject);
IoAttachDeviceToDeviceStack(pnpDeviceObject, diskDeviceObject);
IoRegisterDeviceInterface(
    pnpDeviceObject,
    &GUID_DEVINTERFACE_DISK,
    NULL,
    // out "\??\ROOT#MYFS#0000#{53f56307-b6bf-11d0-94f2-00a0c91efb8b}"
    &diskDeviceName);
IoSetDeviceInterfaceState(&diskDeviceName, TRUE);
IoRegisterDeviceInterface(
    pnpDeviceObject,
    &MOUNTDEV_MOUNTED_DEVICE_GUID,
    NULL,
    // out "\??\ROOT#MYFS#0000#{53f5630d-b6bf-11d0-94f2-00a0c91efb8b}"
    &fsDeviceName);
status = IoSetDeviceInterfaceState(&Dcb->fs_name, TRUE);

// Lets call IOCTL_MOUNTMGR_NEXT_DRIVE_LETTER
status = mountmgr_add_drive_letter(mountmgrDeviceObject, &fsDeviceName);
dprintf("DriveLetterWasAssigned = %u, CurrentDriveLetter = %c\n", mmdli.DriveLetterWasAssigned, mmdli.CurrentDriveLetter);

// Lets call IOCTL_MOUNTMGR_QUERY_POINTS
status = mountmgr_get_drive_letter(mountmgrDeviceObject, &diskDeviceName);

dprintf("   point %d: '%.*S' '%.*S'\n", Index,
    ipoint->DeviceNameLength / sizeof(WCHAR), DeviceName,
    ipoint->SymbolicLinkNameLength / sizeof(WCHAR), SymbolicLinkName);
```

And output generated by the program:

```
** Run code:
WinDeviceObject : FFFFAA81D83CC060
diskDeviceObject: FFFFAA81D260A080
fsDeviceObject  : FFFFAA81D301EC40
=> SendVolumeArrivalNotification

# First requests come in, I don't really know what to do in CREATE/CLEANUP
# and CLOSE, so they mostly just return STATUS_SUCCESS

dispatcher: enter: major 0: minor 0: IRP_MJ_CREATE diskDeviceObject
IRP_MJ_CREATE: FileObject FFFFAA81D6AE8CC0 related 0000000000000000 name '(null)' flags 0x0
Setting FileObject->Vpb to FFFFAA81D559B590
dispatcher: exit: 0x0

dispatcher: enter: major 18: minor 0: IRP_MJ_CLEANUP diskDeviceObject
dispatcher: exit: 0x0

dispatcher: enter: major 2: minor 0: IRP_MJ_CLOSE diskDeviceObject
dispatcher: exit: 0x0

dispatcher: enter: major 0: minor 0: IRP_MJ_CREATE diskDeviceObject
IRP_MJ_CREATE: FileObject FFFFAA81D6AE8CC0 related 0000000000000000 name '(null)' flags 0x0
Setting FileObject->Vpb to FFFFAA81D559B590
dispatcher: exit: 0x0

dispatcher: enter: major 18: minor 0: IRP_MJ_CLEANUP deviceObject FFFFAA81D260A080
dispatcher: exit: 0x0

dispatcher: enter: major 14: minor 0: IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL diskDeviceObject
IOCTL_MOUNTDEV_QUERY_DEVICE_NAME
dispatcher: exit: STATUS_BUFFER_OVERFLOW

dispatcher: enter: major 14: minor 0: IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL diskDeviceObject
IOCTL_MOUNTDEV_QUERY_DEVICE_NAME
replying with '\Device\Volume{0b1bb601-af0b-32e8-a1d2-54c167af6277}'
dispatcher: exit: 0x0

dispatcher: enter: major 14: minor 0: IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL diskDeviceObject
IOCTL_MOUNTDEV_QUERY_UNIQUE_ID
dispatcher: exit: STATUS_BUFFER_OVERFLOW

dispatcher: enter: major 14: minor 0: IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL diskDeviceObject
IOCTL_MOUNTDEV_QUERY_UNIQUE_ID
replying with '\DosDevices\Global\Volume{0b1bb601-af0b-32e8-a1d2-54c167af6277}'
dispatcher: exit: 0x0

dispatcher: enter: major 14: minor 0: IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL diskDeviceObject
IOCTL_MOUNTDEV_QUERY_STABLE_GUID
dispatcher: exit: STATUS_NOT_IMPLEMENTED
# Doesn't sound like I want/need to use stable_guid, so skipping it


dispatcher: enter: major 2: minor 0: IRP_MJ_CLOSE diskDeviceObject
dispatcher: exit: 0x0

dispatcher: enter: major 0: minor 0: IRP_MJ_CREATE diskDeviceObject
IRP_MJ_CREATE: FileObject FFFFAA81D6AE8CC0 related 0000000000000000 name '(null)' flags 0x0
Setting FileObject->Vpb to FFFFAA81D559B590
dispatcher: exit: 0x0

dispatcher: enter: major 18: minor 0: IRP_MJ_CLEANUP diskDeviceObject
dispatcher: exit: 0x0

dispatcher: enter: major 14: minor 0: IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL diskDeviceObject
IOCTL_MOUNTDEV_QUERY_SUGGESTED_LINK_NAME
dispatcher: exit: STATUS_NOT_IMPLEMENTED
# Similarly here, should be ok to go without, right?

dispatcher: enter: major 2: minor 0: IRP_MJ_CLOSE diskDeviceObject
dispatcher: exit: 0x0

dispatcher: enter: major 0: minor 0: IRP_MJ_CREATE diskDeviceObject
IRP_MJ_CREATE: FileObject FFFFAA81D6AE8CC0 related 0000000000000000 name '(null)' flags 0x0
Setting FileObject->Vpb to FFFFAA81D559B590
dispatcher: exit: 0x0

dispatcher: enter: major 18: minor 0: IRP_MJ_CLEANUP diskDeviceObject
dispatcher: exit: 0x0

dispatcher: enter: major 14: minor 0: IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL diskDeviceObject
IOCTL_VOLUME_ONLINE
dispatcher: exit: 0x0

dispatcher: enter: major 14: minor 0: IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL diskDeviceObject
IOCTL_VOLUME_POST_ONLINE
dispatcher: exit: 0x0

dispatcher: enter: major 2: minor 0: IRP_MJ_CLOSE diskDeviceObject

dispatcher: exit: 0x0

<= SendVolumeArrivalNotification

IoReportDetectedDevice success
IoAttachDeviceToDeviceStack success

# Reply to GUID_DEVINTERFACE_DISK
IoRegisterDeviceInterface success: \??\ROOT#MYFS#0000#{53f56307-b6bf-11d0-94f2-00a0c91efb8b}
IoSetDeviceInterfaceState success

# Reply to MOUNTDEV_MOUNTED_DEVICE_GUID
IoRegisterDeviceInterface success: \??\ROOT#MYFS#0000#{53f5630d-b6bf-11d0-94f2-00a0c91efb8b}
IoSetDeviceInterfaceState success

# IOCTL_MOUNTMGR_NEXT_DRIVE_LETTER work
mmdlt = \Device\Myfs{0b1bb601-af0b-32e8-a1d2-54c167af6277}

dispatcher: enter: major 0: minor 0: IRP_MJ_CREATE fsDeviceObject
IRP_MJ_CREATE: FileObject FFFFAA81D2958390 related 0000000000000000 name '(null)' flags 0x0
Setting FileObject->Vpb to FFFFAA81D559B590
dispatcher: exit: 0x0

dispatcher: enter: major 18: minor 0: IRP_MJ_CLEANUP fsDeviceObject
dispatcher: exit: 0x0

dispatcher: enter: major 14: minor 0: IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL fsDeviceObject
IOCTL_MOUNTDEV_QUERY_DEVICE_NAME
dispatcher: exit: STATUS_BUFFER_OVERFLOW

dispatcher: enter: major 14: minor 0: IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL fsDeviceObject
IOCTL_MOUNTDEV_QUERY_DEVICE_NAME
replying with '\Device\Myfs{0b1bb601-af0b-32e8-a1d2-54c167af6277}'
dispatcher: exit: 0x0

dispatcher: enter: major 2: minor 0: IRP_MJ_CLOSE fsDeviceObject
dispatcher: exit: 0x0

DriveLetterWasAssigned = 0, CurrentDriveLetter = D
# Oh, claims it has a drive letter?

IOCTL_MOUNTMGR_QUERY_POINTS return 0
point 0: '\Device\HarddiskVolume1' '\??\Volume{168821f0-0000-0000-0000-100000000000}'
point 1: '\Device\HarddiskVolume2' '\DosDevices\C:'
point 2: '\Device\HarddiskVolume2' '\??\Volume{168821f0-0000-0000-0000-501f00000000}'
point 3: '\Device\Floppy0' '\DosDevices\A:'
point 4: '\Device\Floppy0' '\??\Volume{ffc72bda-0526-11e7-ba78-806e6f6e6963}'
point 5: '' '\??\Volume{5d761629-339b-11e7-baa7-ab3bc3128e46}'
point 6: '' '\DosDevices\D:'
```

Without my code, I would only have 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4. So it would seem
I have created 5 and 6. I don't know what 5 is, the Volume GUID does
not match anything in code, or output. 6 has "D:" like above though...

That "D:" shows up is encouraging, but should the left side
(DeviceName) really be empty? Is that what I should look at next?

Or is it the calls to IRP_MJ_CREATE? I do pretty much nothing but reply
STATUS_SUCCESS. I did assign Vpb to FileObject, but it made no difference.

What is device 5? Is that my problem, is that a generated a name, because I
replied incorrectly somewhere?

Or am I missing a fundamental command?

Hope me Windows Developers...

Answer (score 0):

In the end, it should work, it must be something I did.  Which is pretty much what it comes down to. I had picked up these lines somewhere;

```
  if (Status != STATUS_SUCCESS)
      Irp->IoStatus.Information = 0;
```

Which meant I blew away the "size needed" return integer for the queries probing for name length. Which could not have been answered by anyone just seeing the code here. Now I get a nicer:

```
point 4: '\Device\Volume{0b1bb601-af0b-32e8-a1d2-54c167af6277}'
      '\DosDevices\D:'
```

and a bunch of new queries, including IRP_MJ_DIRECTORY_CONTROL, so I can at least continue. Sorry for the noise.